# Cisco - quickest way to achieve STP convergence after link failure

Tags: switch-statement, cisco, spanning-tree, stp

I am configuring a pair of switches, one each for our two datacentres. We have a pair of links between the sites, one a dedicated private fibre, the other a backup 100Mbps connection. For reasons not worth going into, I need to push a number of VLANs across the links, and need to use STP (or equivalent) to manage path redundancy and avoid a switching loop and the associated melt down.

Currently I have set a path cost of 4096 on the backup link on both the root primary and secondary, which works fine, the switches select the fibre and block the backup link until the fibre is down. I have also set a net-diameter of 2 for the VLANs concerned, which has reduced the convergence time to 14s (2x forward time).

I have read that using RSTP its possible to get convergence in around a second, if this is true, would be interested to know how.

Here's what I have so far (this config is more or less mirrored on both switches):

```
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
spanning-tree vlan 102,104-109 priority 24576
spanning-tree vlan 102,104-109 forward-time 7
spanning-tree vlan 102,104-109 max-age 10
!
<snip>
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/47
 description Pseduo wire to DC2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 102-108
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree vlan 102-108 cost 4096
!         
<snip>
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/49
 description 1Gbps to DC2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 102-107,109
 switchport mode trunk
```

Comment: Remember show output is crucial to troubleshooting- 'show spanning-tree' is your friend- you want every vlan instance to have an 'alternate' port and make sure it's running 802.1w.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even a well tuned RSTP topology [still may need a couple of seconds](http://blog.ine.com/2009/09/07/rstp-and-fast-convergence/), but a good place to start is by adjusting the [3 timers](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk621/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094954.shtml) for RSTP:

```
Hello - which defaults to 2 seconds
Forward Delay - which defaults to 15
Max Age - which defaults to 20 (Less important here)
```

Uplinkfast doesn't need to be configured as it's 'kind-of' built into RSTP, just check that your backup link is listed as an 'Alternate' port and is ready to fail over fast.

For general RSTP housekeeping consider setting all your edge ports to Portfast and considering the impact of any half duplex links on the topology- if possible change all half duplex ports to full duplex, this will make them candidates for using 802.1w (RSTP will fall back to STP on half duplex...)  
**Half duplex is just very bad in RSTP**, but there are workarounds.

Also consider what kind of failure occurs when a link goes down:

**Direct Failure** - Switch is aware link is down immediately (port goes down).
This is very fast to fail over to an alternate port as switch is immediately aware of the problem- here you could possibly achieve <1 second depending on how long switch takes to detect the port is down.

**Indirect Failure** - Traffic is being blackholed, but the switch thinks the link is up.
Much longer to detect as 3xHello Packets must be discarded.
If this is what's happening, consider setting your hello packet timer to 1 second.

(Missing 3 hellos will tell the switch the link is down... 6 seconds vs. 3 seconds)

Comment: Hi Niall, thanks for the post. So to switch to RSTP, is it just a case of changing the spanning-tree statements for each VLAN at the start of the config? I'm happy tuning the STP parameters. I'm mostly concerned about direct link failures so am hoping to get quick convergence.

Comment: The other thing that is perplexing me slightly, is that as things are currently configured (hello time 2s, forward time 7s) even with direct link failure it's still taking 14s to get itself sorted. I would have thought that as you said, direct link failure (i.e. loss of carrier on both switches) should have them switching more rapidly?

Comment: btongeorge.  A lot of unknowns here- I would strongly suggest you set up a lab with 2 switches, and try with a single vlan first before trying a trunk...  take a look at all show output, makes sure each vlan lists an alternate port.

Comment: Complete Cisco config guide included in this pdf:> https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/RPVSpanningTree.pdf

Comment: You could also set up a few SLAs to do the monitoring and limit it to few miliseconds then shutdown the port. Also you can use BFD to achieve fast detection of link failure. Another possibility is using REP.

Answer (score 0):

i need to point out somethings here...

always try to set the **duplex mode and speed the same** for the links, although each interface is getting their speed and duplex configs automatically base on the other port but its ideal that you do it manually.

second you dont need to specify the extended system-id. it is the default mode.

in RSTP every device is talking to its neighbour thats why it is fast! it takes 2 seconds to converge. ( in STP the root bridge is responsible to send TCN (Topology Change Notification) packets for updating the STP status)
in RSTP there is a method that devices talks to each other, and that is sending packets in both ways ( full duplex - and the main reason that RSTP is performing is based on the send and receive at same time - router needs to know that its neighbour port is up, if not the root and designated ports must be change to perform another convergence...)

sorry if my notes were not so clear i tried to explain what is essential to know.
thanks.